# Change value of cell based on input value

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("d10:e309")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        With Range("d10:e309")
            Select Case .Value2
                Case 0
                    'do nothing
                Case 1
                    .Value = 0.01
                Case 5
                    .Value = 0.005
            End Select
        End With
    End If

bm_Safe_Exit:
        Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

I'm wanting the code to use 1 and 5 when inputted into a cell to act as shortcuts to automatically be replaced in the cell inputted in with .01 and .005 respectively

Comment: `With Range("d10:e309")` -----> `With Target`. I'd also add `If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub`, or add a loop if you plan to change multiple cells simultaneously.

Comment: I modified the code with that and it's not doing anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Range("d10:e309").Value2` will be an array.  Comparing an array to a value doesn't work.  Secondly `Target.Value` may be an array too, if more than one cell is changed,  eg by copy paste.  It also may include cells outside your range of interest

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim TargetRange As Range, rng As Range 
    Set TargetRange = Intersect(Target, Range("d10:e309"))
    If Not TargetRange Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each rng In TargetRange 
            Select Case rng.Value2
                Case 0
                    'do nothing
                Case 1
                    Rng.Value = 0.01
                Case 5
                    Rng.Value = 0.005
            End Select
        Next
    End If

bm_Safe_Exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: This code doesn't work, was it meant to to be a solution to my issue..?

Comment: @Claudia if this doesn't work for you then there is something else going on in your sheet (it does work for me).  What debug steps have you taken?

Comment: I have the code on "Module 9", and for debugging as I use the variable of rng somewhere else i changed the variable to trl.

Comment: @Claudia if "Module 9" is a standard module then your code is in the wrong place.  It must be in the Worksheet module for the sheet you want it to run on.

Comment: if I put it in worksheet won't it run a error as my code in there uses
 "Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)"

Comment: It's an event handler, it will _only_ respond to events on a worksheet if it's in the worksheet module.  If by _as my code in there uses "Private Sub Worksheet_Change ..._ you mean there is already code for handling Change events in there, there can be only one of each event type in the worksheet module.  If that's the case you'll need to modify the event handler to cope with all situations you want to respond to

Comment: Thanks, got it functional with this information.